# Wrong colormap when using matlab2tikz for 2D surface plot

Tags: errors, color, matlab2tikz

I am currently using matlab2tikz, trying to import a Matlab surf plot, where I view only two-dimensions:

[image: 2D-surface plot, generated in Matlab]

I am using a custom colormap, but the error occurrs even with the standard colormap.
The problem arises, when importing in Latex:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}

\begin{axis}[%
width=4.585in,
height=3.481in,
at={(0.769in,0.47in)},
scale only axis,
xmin=-8.99723178213376,
xmax=73.9972317821338,
xmajorgrids,
y dir=reverse,
ymin=1,
ymax=64,
ymajorgrids,
hide axis,
axis x line*=top,
axis y line*=left
]

\addplot[%
surf,
shader=flat,colormap={mymap}{[1pt] rgb(0pt)=(0.0416667,0,0); rgb(23pt)=(1,0,0); rgb(47pt)=(1,1,0); rgb(56pt)=(1,1,0.5625)},mesh/rows=64]
table[row sep=crcr, point meta=\thisrow{c}] {%
%
x   y   c\\
1   1   0.125\\
1   2   0.125\\
1   3   0.125\\

...

64  63  -0.0883883476483184\\
64  64  0\\
};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}%
```

This results in an image with wrong colors:

[image]

I already tried to set `point meta min` and `point meta max` manually, but it does not change anything. Do you have any idea how to fix this?